# How to do operations between subsequent rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to Machine Learning and I can't figure out how to perform the following task: I need to subtract two subsequent rows belonging to the same column, but only if the "ID" column value is the same and if the "Year" column values of those rows are consecutive.

A sample of the table:

```
           ID  Year  Revenues
0   180310781  2008  1730.119
1   180310781  2009  1710.073
2   180310781  2010  1653.428
3   180310781  2011  1608.061
4   180310781  2012   1350.84
12  756460796  2008   1061.78
13  756460796  2009  1045.337
14  756460796  2010         0
15  756460796  2011   675.333
16  756460796  2012   671.717
```

The desired outcome is a new column showing 0 (or Nan, I don't care) in the first row since it's the first year of observation, while the result of 1710.073 - 1730.119 in the second row and so on until the equal IDs are exhausted.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False) \
                 .apply(lambda x: x['Revenues'].diff())
```

Outputs

```
          ID  Year  Revenues      Diff
0  180310781  2008  1730.119       NaN
1  180310781  2009  1710.073   -20.046
2  180310781  2010  1653.428   -56.645
3  180310781  2011  1608.061   -45.367
4  180310781  2012  1350.840  -257.221
5  756460796  2008  1061.780       NaN
6  756460796  2009  1045.337   -16.443
7  756460796  2010     0.000 -1045.337
8  756460796  2011   675.333   675.333
9  756460796  2012   671.717    -3.616
```

Answer (score 1):

Can create a Boolean `Series` with `.shift` to verify the conditions, then assign difference to rows where the `Series` is `True`:

```
s = (df.ID == df.ID.shift(1)) & (df.Year == df.Year.shift(1)+1)
df.loc[s, 'Diff'] = df.Revenues.diff()[s]

           ID  Year  Revenues      Diff
0   180310781  2008  1730.119       NaN
1   180310781  2009  1710.073   -20.046
2   180310781  2010  1653.428   -56.645
3   180310781  2011  1608.061   -45.367
4   180310781  2012  1350.840  -257.221
12  756460796  2008  1061.780       NaN
13  756460796  2009  1045.337   -16.443
14  756460796  2010     0.000 -1045.337
15  756460796  2011   675.333   675.333
16  756460796  2012   671.717    -3.616
```

Comment: Slightly more readable version: `df['Diff'] = df['Revenue'].sub(df['Revenue'].shift(1))`